# CodeSandbox: Using terminal in node template

Tags: codesandbox

I'm trying to create a sandbox using the node template but I'm running into issues accessing the terminal. I have a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0joix) that I've uploaded using their [define API](https://codesandbox.io/docs/api#define-api) which should be using a node template (defined in my `sandbox.config.json`) and have a defined start script. It shows a 504 and doesn't give me access to the terminal. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After more research: I now see the sandbox running in a node environment, but no terminal - but hovering over the "+" on the upper right of the info/console window gives a tooltip "Fork to add a Terminal". I did so, and the terminal became available. I conclude it's some form of ownership issue - I can't open a terminal in *your* sandbox, but I can in *my* forked sandbox.

We can conclude that the define API creates a *public* template/sandbox - but the terminal is only available in a *private* sandbox.  To use the terminal, you'll have to fork the sandbox after creating it.

(thx to @codesandbox for including the tooltip that led to the conclusion)

Answer (score 0):

That's not a container environment, which is required to have access to a terminal.  There are known issues with containers & codesandbox; specifically, you can't convert one sandbox type to another, and sometimes forking from someone else's github also does not create as a container.

Best to start with a containerized template.

Comment: do you know how to specify a container environment? In my `sandbox.config.json`, I have the template set to `node`; is there another setting I should use there?

Comment: Did you *select* a node template when you started, or edit the sandbox.config.json to change it to 'node'?   As I understand it, you can't *change* the environment; it has to be set at the start to use the containerized environment.  I learned this the hard way - had a bunch of code imported, then had to create *another* containerized sandbox, and use an *external* git client to merge existing code into containerized sandbox.

Comment: Hm. On more poking about, I now see the sandbox running in a node environment, but no terminal - but hovering over the "+" on the upper right of the info/console window gives a tooltip "Fork to add a Terminal".  I did so, and the terminal became available.  I suspect it's some form of ownership issue - *I* can't open a terminal in *your* sandbox, but I *can* in my *forked* sandbox.  I suspect the way you used the  define API  either creates a *template*, or some other way affects the ownership.

Comment: Okay, I suppose it makes sense that terminals aren't public, though I wish it would run my start script and not look like it errors out :/

@LeadDreamer if you want to update your answer (or re-answer) to say that terminals are private and the define API is public, so this approach won't work, I'll accept that as the answer 

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone: to enable containers for an existing project you need to create a sandbox.config.json file with the following content before creating the sandbox:

```
{
  "template": "node"
}
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to change the sandbox once it's created.

Ref: https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/1608